# Start gnome-terminal with multiple virtualenv tabs and services, pre-titled

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenv, gnome-terminal

I'm working on a server-side project that consists of several services. Each service is run in interactive (i.e. non-daemon) mode, this is handy while active development. The project is in virtualenv. So the typical way to start a service is:

```
$ cd ~/to/vitualenv/subdir/where/service/code/located
$ source ../path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
$ ./script-to-start-service
+ Set title of terminal to the service name via GUI
```

It would be ok if there were 2-3 services at all. But we have a dozen. And restarting all of them after computer reboot is a real pain.

So what I want is a script, that once executed opens me new gnome-terminal window with a dozen of named tabs (one per service), with activated virtualenv in each and running bunch of service instances in that tabs. The best result I've got so far is:

```
$ gnome-terminal --working-directory=~/to/vitualenv/subdir --window --tab --tab
```

--title and --profile looks like been ignored and if --command is specified newly opened window is closed just in moment after open.

Any ideas? How to source activation script, give a title, and run service?

P.S. It is for development purposes only, not for deployment on real servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me and do what you requested:

`gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/wd --tab-with-profile=profile1 --title=title1 -e 'bash --rcfile /path/to/rcfile1.sh' --tab-with-profile=profile2 --title=title2 -e 'bash --rcfile /path/to/rcfile2.sh'`

Comment: Wow! Works at most. But is there a way to throw rcfile*.sh files away? With pipes or so

Answer (score 0):

Create a gnome-terminal profile named "service" (Edit > Profiles > New).

In Edit > Profile Preferences > Title and Command > Run a custom command instead of my shell, set the custom command to:

```
bash --rcfile ../path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
```

Then use gnome-terminal to launch your services. The following command launches two instances of `yes` in tabs in different directories. I've broken the command into three lines, but you should enter it as one line.

```
gnome-terminal
--tab-with-profile=service --working-directory=/home/$USER/data --title="feelgood" --command="yes"
--tab-with-profile=service --working-directory=/code --title="negative" --command="yes no"
```

---

Instead of directly calling activate, you may want to create a file to use as your custom command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
source ../path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
```

You can also add commands (like change directory or launching your service). Just beware that every time you open a terminal with that profile, those commands are executed.